# Hide a div Only after all the content of Ajax response has been rendered

Tags: javascript, ajax, scripting

I want a loader div in my javascript to be hidden only after the response content from ajax call has been filled and redered completely in the view. I have tried the following code but loader doesnot hide even after rendering is complete.

```
function fxnname()
{
    document.getElementById('report_div').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    {  
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("report_div").innerHTML=this.responseText;
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
            });
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","TheURL.PHP?q="+year,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have added a div with id tablend at the end of table to ensure that loader goes off when table rendering is complete as well as dumy div after that table is also rendered. It check after every 1000 that whether the dummy tableend div has been rendered or not. I updated the code as below:

```
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("report_div").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
       var tablend = document.getElementById("tablend");
       if (tablend) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
       }
    }, 1000)
}
```

This time it looks like things are working but, still loader goes off before the styling has been done. Also, The page is still loaded with alot of data so, if I click the same button again, application responds too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use `DOMContentLoaded` just do like

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("report_div").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: I was doing this initially but the loader goes off far before the content and styling has been completey rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding the event listener after the DOMContentLoaded event already occured (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) for reference), so the callback function that changes the display value of your loading element is never executed. I suggest trying a different approach to determine if the content of report_div has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event doesn't have any connection to AJAX requests.  It fires when the browser has finished parsing initial page resources.  See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).  The div isn't being hidden because the callback that hides it is never called.

You could use javascript to fire your own event whenever the requested data is loaded and corresponding DOM elements are updated.  In this case you could add the event listener to the document right away, before you even make the request.  However, the alternative I would suggest is to use a more modern request API like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) instead of the XMLHttpRequest object.  These APIs allow you to express asynchronous control flows in a more declarative syntax that is easier to read and (arguably) also easier to write.  E.g. using the fetch api:

```
fetch(my/resource/url)
.then(response => JSON.parse(response))
.then(json => functionToUpdateDOM(json))
.then(functionToHideLoadingDiv())
.catch(error => functionToHandleError(error))
```